# How to download and process data from the internet without writing it as file?

Tags: python, python-requests

In python 3.6.8 I am trying to download a 'file' from a URL and process it directly, without creating a local file. I have tried the following code

```
import io
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enzoftware/random/master/README.md"

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with io.BytesIO(response.text) as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

but I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 7, in <module>
    with io.BytesIO(response.text) as f:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you just want to read it line by line rather than considering any document (html) structure it may have you can just do

```
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enzoftware/random/master/README.md"

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
for line in response.text.splitlines():
    print (line)
```

Comment: thanks, yes even better. I was thinking way to complicated again!